# Spring Jersey REST: arrays with ONE element issue

Tags: json, spring, rest, jersey

I am using spring and jersey. Problem with this combo is when trying to create a json where an objects has List and there is only one element. If there are many, json is fine. Jersey "forgot" to add brackets [] on single elems.

As you can see, even tried to force it to use jackson (as I read in many tutorials), but ... same result:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;au.com.bikesquare.core.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </servlet>
```

Then found this, and still nothing.

```
@Provider
@Component
@Produces ("application/json")
public class JsonJaxbResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
@Override
public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
    JSONConfiguration.MappedBuilder b = JSONConfiguration.mapped();
    b.arrays("to");
    try {
        return new JSONJAXBContext(b.build(), EmailMessageTransferObject.class);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Server where I am trying to send my object (that contains list) captures this:

```
....
"to": {
        "email": "aaa@bbb.ccc",
        "name": "aaa"
    }
....
```

Supposed to be:

```
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "aaa@bbb.ccc",
            "name": "aaa"
        }
    ],
```

My class (parts of it):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EmailMessageTransferObject {
    ...
    @XmlElement
    private List<EmailRecipientTransferObject> to;
    ...
}
```

Any ideas? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer later:

```
@Provider
@Produces ("application/json")
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

private JAXBContext context;
private Class<?>[] types = {SendEmailMessageTransferObject.class};

public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
    this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("to").build(), types);
}

@Override
public JAXBContext getContext(Class objectType) {
    for (Class type : types) {
        if (type == objectType) {
            return context;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Client:

```
public MandrillRestMailImpl() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getClasses().add(JAXBContextResolver.class);
    client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));   //todo: remove this for prod
}
```